# Spy++: WM_ACTIVATEAPP gives a thread-id that does not exist, why?

Tags: c#, winapi, spy++

I am trying to develop an app that can bring another app to foreground, so I analyze the behaviour of Windows Explorer (Alt-Tab) using Spy++, for me it is interesting which app or which threis actually activated, so I monitor the message WM_ACTIVATEAPP.

WM_ACTIVATEAPP, when wparam=false, according to the MSDN documentation, lparam represents the threadid of the thread being activated.

Here is an example from my Spy++ log:
<00037> 00030DD6 S WM_ACTIVATEAPP fActive:False **dwThreadID:000008F0**

My problem is: the given dwThreadID **8F0** should be the application that gets activated. But: when I switch to the thread-view in Spy++, and search for a thread **8F0**, I find nothing. That thread seems not to exist at all. So how do I translate this thread-ID to a process ID?

Comment: Perhaps the thread is ended shortly after the window is activated.

Comment: > So how do I translate this thread-ID to a process ID?

`GetProcessIdOfThread`.

Comment: So, uhm, what's there to analyze? Just call [`SetForegroundWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539.aspx) and be done with it. If you object, that `SetForegroundWindow` fails under certain conditions, don't hold your breath: The same conditions prevent sending `WM_ACTIVATEAPP` from actually activating that application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lots of reasons for this, but the most common one is that Spy++ does **not** give you a live view of the machine state.  It makes a snapshot when you start it, that snapshot can rapidly become stale.  Refreshing a window like Spy + Threads is something you have to do by hand.  Use Window + Refresh or press F5.

While that sounds like a pretty nasty flaw, it is actually intentional.  Iterating all of the threads and (especially) all of the windows that exist on the machine is a pretty expensive operation.  A debugging tool that has too much of an impact on what's being observed is not a trustworthy tool.

Just get in the habit of pressing F5 when you can't see what you think should be there.